# User input problems in a simple bash script multiplication problems

Tags: bash, shell, math

Simple program to caclulate the square and then check if the user gets it right.

It throws an error saying "guess.sh: [4: not found" with 4 being the answer that the user entered. I know I'm missing something incredibly simple...

```
echo "Please enter a number "

read number

SQUARE=$((number*number))

echo "please enter the answer"

read answer

if ["$SQUARE" -eq "$answer"]
then
    echo "well done"
else
    echo "sorry wrong answer"
fi
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a space after  `[` as it is a command

```
ls -l /usr/bin/[
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 35248 Jan 26  2013 /usr/bin/[
```

(and before `]` too, of course)

```
if [ "$SQUARE" -eq "$answer" ]
then
    echo "well done"
else
    echo "sorry wrong answer"
fi
```

or

```
read -p "Enter a number: " number
square=$[number**2]
read -p "Enter his square: " second
if ((second==square)) ;then
    echo well done
  else
    echo wrong square
fi
```

Work too, but it's based on so-called *bashisms*

Comment: +1 for explaining the open bracket is a command!  You could also use the word "test" and not use the closing bracket.